Isekai manhwa where the male lead is from Korea and his wife can calm his magic when he goes overboard
I want to find a manhwa where the male lead (who is from Korea and has black hair) got isekaied to the female lead's world. They married each other because the wife can calm his magic and they have a strong bond. But she dies by calming his power and she got reincarnated in a noble lady's body. I think she has pink hair? And she is weak. But she meets her ex-husband and hopes that he will not recognize her, because she was mistreated by him.

Is the ex-husband you mentioned near the end of your description the male lead or a different character?

Its the male lead, the same one who married her before she died and got reincarnated

I juste remembered that the male lead has a little brother

After weeks of searching, i finally found it = How to reject my obsessive ex-husband

You should consider posting a proper answer via the 'Your Answer' field below. Each upvote it gets will add 10 points to your reputation score. If you do post a proper answer, please also remember to mark it as accepted by clicking on the grey check mark on the left side of the answer. However, as it would be a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours after the question was first posted before the site will let you do that. If another user posts the answer first, you'll be able to mark it as accepted right away.

Copied in an answer from the other question for the same work to mark this as answered. If you would prefer to have the answer in your own name, feel free to use it as a basis and repost. I should be able to delete my answer.

As stated in the comments, this is How To Reject My Obsessive Ex-Husband.

When Yu Seohyeon sacrificed her life to save her first love, Ciel de Leopart, she never expected to wake up as Irene de Closhe in a world straight out of a book. Amidst this bizarre twist, she reunites with Ciel, who has now become a supporting male lead destined to betray the crown prince. As her unique guide abilities resurface, Seohyeon is haunted by Ciel's intense, madness-filled gaze, a stark contrast to the man she once knew. Tangled in a web of past love and new identities, Seohyeon must navigate a treacherous path where past and present collide.

The protagonist is a guide, her husband is an esper.

Espers have uncontrollable powers but guides can help bring it under control. The story opens with the ML's powers going berserk, killing both of them. The FL reincarnates in a book world and rediscovers her husband at a palace banquet. She has a different appearance and name, but he does not, so she recognizes him immediately but he only gets a vague sense of familiarity.
As the title suggests, he is obsessively in love with her and seeks her out after discovering that she also reincarnated.
